# iframe body is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to modify the specific divs within an IFrame using Jquery.

This is the html for the IFrame:

```
<iframe  frameborder="0" height="1588px" id="j_id1" name="j_id1" src="https://example.com/page.html" title="Content" width="100%"></iframe></body></html>
```

I've tried the following:

```
console.log('iframe body: '+j$('#j_id1').contents().find('body').html());

j$('#j_id1').contents().find('div').each(function(){
    console.log(j$(this).text());
});
```

However, this outputs:

```
iframe body: null
```

How can I access and modify the contents of the IFrame?

Comment: Your console log is looking for a `<j_id1>...</j_id1>` element.

Comment: Isn't it a cross domain iframe?!

Comment: If source doesn't belong to your domain then you can't read its HTML content, as it is against the Browser Policy (Security Reasons)

Comment: Probably because the problem is Origin Policy, which is a sore subject around here :D Is the iframe that you trying to manipulate on the same domain and is the origin https?

Comment: @eithedog yes, same domain with https

Comment: So, you can actually replace the `http://example.com/page.html` with `//page.html` (it's totally fine that you're accessing it via absolute paths). Can you please console log the `j$('#j_id1')` (so there's actually one element with such id and that's actually the iframe you want to target). Also, can you then console log `j$('#j_id1').contents()` (it should output the `window` object, not the `document` - if I remember correctly in versions of jquery <1.8 you couldn't traverse through `window`, but had to use window.documentElement / window.document.

Comment: @eithedog I've tried that but nothing gets printed :(

Comment: Time to check errors in your code then (or the logic for console log) :D

If you're willing to put your code on jsfiddle.net, it will be easier to determine where's the problem

Answer (score 1):

As a [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) user, I can provide you with this:

```
document.getElementById('j_id1').contentDocument.body
```

Sadly I don't know how to do it in jQuery exactly, but this hybrid would work:

```
$(document.getElementById('j_id1').contentDocument.body).find("div").doSomething...
```

**HOWEVER**, you can only do this if the iframe is from the same scheme, hostname and port number. Which in your case it is not. Consider "proxying" the target site via a PHP file on your own server.

Comment: This way I get TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Just to be sure, you're running this code in a `.ready` or otherwise deferred until after the iframe's loaded, right?